# why one symbol not work for MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I  have some query:

```
delete from swi
    where co||na in (
        select co||na
        from swi
        where co||na not in (
            select co||na
            from swi_tmp
        )
    )
```

and it works on ORACLE DB. But in MS SQL this does not work. How I can get this query to work?

Comment: Quote them ... `select [co||na] from swi_tmp`

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate two columns or you really have a literal `||` as part of the column name?

Comment: @YogeshSharma it is still not working

Comment: @АлександрПлющев correct at all where you find `co||na` with `[co||na]`

Comment: @YogeshSharma Invalid column name 'co||na'.

Comment: Note that in Oracle `where (co, na) in (select co, na ...)` would be better and probably more efficient as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is string concatenation operator as called out in the other answers and comments. However, the concatenation method prevents a [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable) expression so indexes on the columns cannot be used efficiently. This is very bad for concurrency since the DELETE will need to perform a full scan, touching all rows in the table instead of only those that are needed.

You could refactor the query to use `EXISTS` to allow efficient index use and specify table aliases to avoid ambiguity:

```
DELETE FROM swi
WHERE EXISTS( 
        SELECT 1
        FROM swi AS a
        WHERE a.co = swi.co
            AND a.na = swi.na
            AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM swi_tmp AS b
            WHERE 
                b.co = swi.co
                AND b.na = swi.na
        )
    );
```

And better, remove the redundant `EXISTS`, which will be true for all rows anyway (except `NULL` values):

```
DELETE FROM swi
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM swi_tmp
    WHERE 
        swi_tmp.co = swi.co
        AND swi_tmp.na = swi.na
        );
```

Note that saragable expressions will improve performance in all RDBMS products, not just SQL Server, and are a best practice.

Comment: That is also the better solution in Oracle

Comment: I'll improve my answer with that info.

Comment: @АлександрПлющев, I don't understand your question. My answer includes the only query in your question. I think it will work with `Oracle` too.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have a similar question with other query and I need a help(((

Comment: @АлександрПлющев, what other query? There is only one in your question.

Comment: @DanGuzman Other query in other question)) can you help me if I put here link to other question on stackoverflow?

Comment: I'll take a look if you provide the link to your question.

Comment: @DanGuzman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594139/rewrite-query-for-sql-server-from-oracle and I want ask, really create one query for postregressql, oracle, and mssql?

Answer (score 3):

Because SQL Server uses `+` for string concatenation not the `||` operator that is defined in the SQL standard.

You probably need `co+na` instead of `co||na`

Comment: Bingo. But they should use a different approach. This string concatenation approach is pretty horrible and may not behave as they want. e.g. `('abc', 'def')` will be treated the same as  `('abcd', 'ef')`

Comment: @MartinSmith: I completely agree. In Oracle `where (co, na) in (select co, na ...)` would be a much better choice, but that isn't possible in SQL Server if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: No it isn't possible in SQL Server you would need to use `EXISTS` / `NOT EXISTS` rather than `IN`/`NOT IN` here

Answer (score -1):

As a general rule, don't use special characters (that includes white space) and reserved words when naming objects. If you do, like @Yogesh stated, you have to quote them using brackets. Names like the following would have to be quoted  `[co||an]`, `[Order]`, `[Total Value]` because they contain special characters or are a reserved word (*order*).

Comment: `||` is not a "special character". It's the string concatenation operator in SQL.

Comment: No `+` is used in T-SQL to concatenate. `SELECT 'Hello' + ' ' + 'Goodbye';` `||` in SQL Server is simply a double pipe, it has no other meaning.

Comment: In "SQL" (the standard for query languages) `||` **is** the operator for string concatenation. And it has been that for nearly 30 years now. SQL Server (or actually Sybase back when they created SQL Server) chose to ignore that standard and uses `+` in T-SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is a SQL-server and T-SQL question. hence the answers you provide need to be for T-SQL, not other (SQL) languages. SAying something works in Oracle or MySQL doesn't mean it'll work in T-SQL, for the same reason a T-SQL solution might not work in Oracle or MySQL, etc. The lanugages **are** different (despite there being standards that none of them completely follow).

Comment: I answered for T-SQL - your answer assuming that there is a column that is named `co||an` is wrong because in Oracle the expression `co||an` means "`co` concatenated with `an`" - so there is one column named `co` and one named `an`

Comment: You can't have. `co||an` is invalid syntax for T-SQL for the above reasons. The string concatenation character in T-SQL is `+`. Your answer is like bringing a C# answer to a VB.Net question.

Comment: The query in the question is the original Oracle query. And to translate that to T-SQL you need to replace `||` with `+` there is no column wit the name `co||an` in the question