# Rewrite query for SQL Server from Oracle

Tags: sql-server

I have query, help me rewrite it for SQL Server:

```
insert into swi (co, na, ci, ac, id, version, add) 
    select co, na, ci, acc, id, ?, address 
    from swi_tmp 
    where co||me not in (select co||me from swi)
```

Now, I have, but it still not working

```
insert into swi (co, na, ci, ac, id, version, add) 
    select co, na, ci, acc, id, ?, address 
    from swi_tmp 
    where not exists (select 1 
                      from swi_tmp
                      where swi_tmp.co = swi.co and swi_tmp.na = swi.na)
```

Comment: Please try it yourself and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FROM` clause in the `NOT EXISTS` subquery is using the source table instead of the target table. Change the table name in the NOT EXISTS subquery to the target table name:

```
INSERT INTO swi (co, na, ci, ac, id, version, add) 
    SELECT co, na, ci, acc, id, ?, address 
    FROM swi_tmp 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      FROM swi
                      WHERE
                          swi_tmp.co = swi.co
                          AND swi_tmp.na = swi.na
                     );
```

Comment: Thank you very much!:) I can check this query only on Monday. Can I expect that this query and query before this will works fine on postgress, oracle and mssql, or this only in my dreams and I must write 2 or 3 different queries for each db?

Comment: Most major DBMS products implement the ANSI-92 standard SQL so I would expect it to work with Oracle and PostgreSQL too but I have not tried it.

Comment: sorry, but this query throw this exception "java.sql.SQLException: The multi-part identifier "swi.co" could not be bound." why?

Comment: @АлександрПлющев, the error suggests column `co` does not exist in table `swi`. What DBMS is returning that error?